# Im trying to find if a number is a prime or not and an error throws "The operator && is undefined for the argument type int int"

Tags: java

```
public class prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a=2;
        
        if (a/=2  && a/=1)
            System.out.println(a + "is a prime number");
        else
            System.out.println(a +"is not a prime number");
        
    }

}
```

P.S- this is my 3rd code that Im writing all on my own.!!
not sure if conceptually I am on the right path to find the answer.. some help will be really appreciated

Comment: What do you think `a/=2` does?

Comment: `a /= 2` means "take a, divide it by 2 and store it back to a", which is definetly wrong here.
`a` is an int, not a boolean. The `&&` operator is meant for booleans.

Comment: `a/=2` - what is your intention with this?

Comment: && operator take boolean type operand  ,but your expression return number

Comment: understood. but to find if a number is prime or not. I will have to divide the number by itself at some point right?

Comment: in a/=2 im trying to place the first condition which is required to check if the number is prime or not.!!

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/examples/prime-number

Comment: what does this "boolean flag = false;" mean in the above link?

Comment: By `a/=2` are you trying to say "a is not equal to 2"? If that is the case, you want `a != 2`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 1):

The operator `&&` (logical and) is a short-circuit logical boolean operator. You need boolean expressions to use it. `/=` is a shorthand for division and assigning. `a /= 2` is `a = a / 2`. This is not a boolean expression, so you can't use an `&&` operator.

It's worth looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for a summary of assignment operators like `/=` and logical operators like `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need "%" to check if number is divide completely. "%" is [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and number is divide completely if remainder is equal to 0.
2. Probably you misunderstood the task. You need to check if number does not divide completely. The number can be divide completely only by them self and by 1. So you need to check if number is divide completely by all smaller positive numbers (for n it will be n-1, ..., 2, if you will consider 2, then you start from 2 - 1, so you start from 1, and 1 < 2, so you don't check any number). If you found at lest one such nuber that divide completely your number, then your number is not prime. If you don't find, then your number is prime.
   E.g when n is 7, you need to chekc if 7 is divide completely by 6, 5, 4, 3, 2. It will be 7%6 == 1, 7%5 == 2, 7%4 == 3, ... (you will don't get 7 % X == 0, there is no such X, so 7 is prime)
   When n is 8, you need to check 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2.
   And it will be 8 % 7 == 1, 8 % 6 == 2, 8 % 5 == 3, 8 % 4 == 0 (you found 8 % X == 0, it will be for 4 and for 2, to 8 is not a prime)

```
if(n % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println(n + "is divide completely by 2");
} else {
    System.out.println(n + "is not divide completely by 2");
}
```

```
int x = 7;
int y = 5;
System.out.println("remainder of dividing x by y is "+(x % y));
```